# How to make a fade in animation for each item in GridView using QML

Tags: javascript, qt, animation, gridview, qml

I am trying to make a fade in animation everytime the model of the gridview changes.
I am trying to make use of the example mention in the link:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-gridview.html#delayRemove-prop

But i'm trying to do it on the attached signal onAdd.

Is it possible or is there a workaround i can use??

Below is my code

```
        GridView{
            id:productGView
            height: 100
            width: 100
            anchors{
                left: parent.left; top: parent.top;
            }
            cellHeight:20;
            cellWidth: 20;
            keyNavigationWraps :true
            delegate: Image{
                id:gridDel
                height: productGView.cellHeight
                width: productGView.cellWidth
                source:(productGView.currentIndex==index)?("item_h.png"):("item_n.png")
                GridView.onAdd: SequentialAnimation {
                    PropertyAction { target: gridDel; property: "GridView.delayRemove"; value: true }
                    NumberAnimation { target: gridDel; property: "scale"; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
                    PropertyAction { target: gridDel; property: "GridView.delayRemove"; value: false }
                }
                GridView.onRemove: {
                    core.log("Del | onRemove | index = "+index)
                }

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    core.log("Del | onCompleted | index = "+index)
                }
            }
            snapMode: GridView.SnapToRow
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding an item to the view, it does not need to be guarded against removal, so you can simplify the `GridView.onAdd` handler by removing both `PropertyAction`s, and then also the `SequentialAnimation` becomes unnecessary.

In your code, the `NumberAnimation` animates the scale to `0`, making the individual delegates infinitely small as a result. Try this:

```
delegate: Image {
     ..
     ..
   scale: 0 /* When a delegate is created, scale is initially zero */
   GridView.onAdd: NumberAnimation { 
          target: gridDel
          property: "scale"
          to: 1  /* When the delegate is added to the view, */
                 /* the scale will be animated to 1 */
          duration: 250
          easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
   }
```